# how to insert user-glyphicon in img tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is :- In below code I want to make it, if there is no photo uploaded then there will be a photo size bootstrap's glyphicon-user should be placed and when photo uploaded this will overwrite by the uploaded image.

//please add necessary files of bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="heading">Upload Patient's Photo :-</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="patientpic" id="patientpic" onchange="readURL(this)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//this is the script code for preview image when uploaded.

```
    <script>
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#patientimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
         }
        </script>                               
    </div>
```

//this is image code here changes takes place to add bootstrap's glyphicon-user

```
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="" alt="Select Patient Image" class="img-responsive" id="patientimg" name="patientimg" style="height:140px;width:140px;font-size:30px;text-align:center;color:gray;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried this but the glyphicon-user in span tag reside below patient image.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I tried it with <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> but where to place it in img tag

Comment: You can't add **anything** *into* an image.tag except an image

Comment: then how to solve above problem

Comment: if you can provide a screen shot/illustration of what you want to do, maybe I can picture and get your idea @sandeep_1994

Comment: Thanks but i know this i just want to use glyphicon.

Answer (score 0):

just suggestion here, why not convert the bootstrap's glyphicon-user to png then add it on  since when the user upload the image it will be appended according to your code.

check a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/ws3bb7sr/1/

```js
       function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#patientimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
         }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="heading">Upload Patient's Photo :-</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="patientpic" id="patientpic" onchange="readURL(this)"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
    
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://s5.postimg.org/4xpbh5oo3/user_000000_128.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="patientimg" name="patientimg" style="height:140px;width:140px;font-size:30px;text-align:center;color:gray;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but please try to do it by glyphicon because I want to know and thanks for your suggestions but I know this to with user image.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best idea, but you can use this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
#img1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
#img1::before {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 100px;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#img1').attr('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0ac72a/0011ff');
        }, 2500);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" id="img1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk">
</body>
</html>
```

You might have some problems with transparent png files, so in better check it. If you have some problem with it you can remove the glyphicon classes when you update the src of your image.